# Connect Magento to Oracle database

Tags: configuration

It is possible to connect Magento to Oracle database. If yes, Then can I know the way how to do that?

Comment: Please be more specific: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to replace MySQL with Oracle or is this a question about integrating another system like the Oracle ERP?

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not support anything else other than MySQL out of the box.
[As stated here by Ben Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9167576/2047249), it seams that this is an option for EE 1.11 + but you will have to request an additional module from Magento support.